# About singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

F(z)= exp{z/(1-cosz)} has what kind of singularity at z=0?
I try to solve the question by doing 
exp[1/{1-cosz/z}] then if we apply limit z approches 0 it will become 'e' which is finite ,so the singularity will be removable,but when i solve the question by expending the question the singularity cames out to be essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking limits along real axis we get $F(0-)=0$ and $F(0+)=\infty$. This implies that $F$ has an  essential singularity at $0$.

Comment: Sir, but I'm getting 1/e and e as left and right limit while aprroching to 0 along x axis( real axis) .

Comment: @gauravsaini Can you show me how you got those limits? Did you use L'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: For left limit exp[1/{1-cosh/(-h)}]=1/e ,and right limit exp[1/{1-cosh/(h)}]= e

Comment: You have typed $F(z)=e^{z/(1-cos \, z)}$ in the question. Why are you changing $\cos\, z$ to $cosh\, z$?.

Comment: Cos(0-h) applying left hand limit

Comment: In my answer I am talking about $\lim_{t \to 0+} F(t)$ and $\lim_{t \to 0-} F(t)$ and these limits do not involve any complex number or cosine hyperbolic functions.

Comment: That is not hyperbolic function jus applying left lift 1-cos(0-h)= 1- cosh

Comment: $\lim_{t \to 0+}\frac t {1-\cos\, t}=\lim_{t \to 0+} \frac 1 {\sin\, t}=\infty$ by L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: @gauravsaini Please use Mathjax or, failing that, at least write $\cos(h)$ for clarity.

Comment: Sir, I'm getting what you want to say ,but can we  solve  this question like this lim(x--->0) [x/(1-cosx)] = [1/(1-cosx/x)] ?

Comment: $lim_{x\to 0} \frac {1-\cos x} x=0$.

Comment: i apologize sir, i was doing it wrong ,thnx for correcting me

Answer (score 1):

$\exp(z)$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$ and $z/(1-\cos z)$ has a pole at $z =0$, so $\exp\left[z/(1-\cos z)\right]$ has an essential singularity at $z = 0 $.

Comment: The method I'm applying here  Exp{1/(1-cosz/z)} is wrong way to solve the question ?

Comment: @gauravsaini $z/(1-\cos z) = 1/[1/z - \cos(z)/z]$, not $1/[1-\cos(z)/z]$

Comment: If you take z common then both are same things

Comment: Then it needs to be written as $1/[(1-\cos z)/z]$. Brackets and parentheses are your friends. Anyways, $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} (1-\cos z) /z = 0$, so your limit will still diverge.